# AlpineJS variable is reactive at first set only

Tags: alpine.js

I'm working on a Laravel app. I already wrote 4 Alpine data stores with no problem at all.
But for the 5th, I'm getting crazy. My `unread` variable is initiated as an empty array.
Then when I first set it, the reactivity works. I have a counter showing the length in the variable. As I loop again to get new values on the server side, the `unread` variable is set again. Its length is increasing but no reactivity in DOM.

```js
    Alpine.store('header', {
        timer: null,
        unread: [],

        init: function(event) {
            this.timer = window.setInterval(this.refreshNotifications, 10000);
            this.refreshNotifications();
        },

        refreshNotifications: function() {
            axios.get('/api/notifications/admin/'+admin.id)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
                    this.unread = response.data;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
    })
```

```html
<!-- Notification badge -->
<span
    x-show="$store.header.unread.length > 0"
    x-text="$store.header.unread.length"
></span>
```

At first load, counter displays 1. In the background, I add a new notification. Axios gets it and returns it, no problem.
A console.log in the Axios promise shows the right value.
But counter remains at 1.

Couple of lines below, I have a `<template x-for ...` and it has the same issue. It doesn't update. I may be very tired but I really can't see the trick.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT : I tried many things including setting a getter method "getCount" or others things.

Comment: How does the `response.data` look like?

Comment: When you set it, you override the reactivity handler, why not just fill the empty array?

Comment: @Marc you mean with a for loop and array push ?

Comment: I did a 

```
response.data.forEach(element => {
 this.unread.push(element);
})
```

A `console.log` works fine but no reactivity. I checked into the Alpine developers tool tab. The `unread` variable remains unreactive. 

I don't get it

edit: great, i can't format code, nice one stackoverflow.

Comment: @dauros as for your question, I can't post it as it is too long for Stackoverflow !?!??!
It's a JSON encode response from a Laravel collection

Comment: You don't have to share the whole response data, just a small, representative subset of it, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I think I'm starting to figure it out. At each window.setInterval, I did a `console.log(typeof this.unread);`.  At first run, it is an object. Every next turn, it becomes undefined. So my var is unset at some point.....